# Segment a webpage by its image

Tags: webpage-screenshot, image-segmentation, background-foreground

I want to segment a webpage and extract out the boxes containing the foreground objects from the background. Please tell what are the methods I can use for this. Here is a the sample image of a webpage and the corresponding output I am trying to achieve Which I made by hand.

[image: Input image]

[image: Output]